# Display image in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have already uploaded the image in a folder and stored its path in the database field. I am trying to display image like this:
Controller:

```
public function showProfileImage($id)
    {
        $profileimage = UserProfileModel::where(['usrID' => $id])->first();

        return view('userlogin::welcome')->with('profileimage', $profileimage->userPicpath);

    }
```

my blade template has:

```
 <img src="{{ route('showprofileimage', ['id' => Session::get('loggedinuserid')]) }}" height="150" />
```

But the path returned in the src is the route path, it doesn't contain the 'profileimage' path returned form the controller. How do i do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `route('<named route>')` helper function returns the URL to a page/endpoint/resource that was defined as:

```
Route::get('some/uri', ['as' => 'showprofileimage', function() {
    //
});
```

It may not be used for displaying images (although it could be used with a few tweaks), but I would go with either one of the following approaches:

If you have the fully qualified image URL then you can use the `url()` helper function. Do:

```
<img src="{{ url('showprofileimage') }}" ... />
```

If your image is in the `/public` directory, you can use the `asset()` helper function:

```
<img src="{{ asset('path/to/profile/image') }}" ... />
```

If your image is in the `/storage` directory, you can use the `storage()` helper function (but I believe this is not recommended):

```
<img src="{{ storage('path/to/profile/image') }}" ... />
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!